# What's the difference between #{cc.foo} and #{cc.attrs.foo}?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm trying to add something to a composite component somebody else created and there is a `#{cc.foo}` in there. I can't seem to find where `foo` is defined, even doing a grep over the entire codebase.

What's the difference between `cc.attrs.foo` and `cc.foo` in general?

**EDIT** I found it in some jar, therefore I didn't see it in the search. Still the question generally remains. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is `foo`? Composite components (as other `UIComponent`s) have certain properties predefined: for example, `#{cc.rendered}` or `#{cc.clientId}` are defined by the Java EE spec, not the user, so they are always available within composite components.

In general, `#{cc.whatever}` will be properties of the component itself: its component ID `#{cc.id}`, its client ID (i.e. what's rendered as the `id` attribute of the HTML tag) `#{cc.clientID}`, its parent component `#{cc.parent}`, etc. These are provided by Java EE. On the other hand, `#{cc.attrs.whatever}` are provided by the component developer: they will be the named attributes of the composite component: for each `<composite:attribute name="myAttribute" ... />` in the `<composite:interface>` section of the composite component file, there will be a `#{cc.attrs.myAttribute}` available to use in the `<composite:implmenentation>` section of the composte component file.

Comment: I don't know :( I cannot find it in any .java file and I didn't create the composite component. How would I find out?

Comment: Oh ok, it is `invalidEntriesCount`. But see my EDIT above, I found it in a jar. Thanks

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to cover the general case.